Safe propose transaction error handling
I have the following piece of code
    const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
      transactions: [safeTransactionData],
      options: { nonce: nextNonce },
    });

    const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
    const signature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash);

    await service.proposeTransaction({
      safeAddress: await safeSdk.getAddress(),
      safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
      safeTxHash,
      senderAddress: await signer.getAddress(),
      senderSignature: signature.data,
    });

    return { hash: safeTxHash, error: null };

When I call it in certain cases it fails

I see the following if I inspect the network call:
{"to":["Address 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48 is not checksumed"]}
However the try / catch error block just gives me an empty error object.
How would I handle these cases? Here's what the docs in my IDE tell me

But it doesn't seem to behave that way.
Using:
"@safe-global/api-kit": "^2.0.0",
"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^2.0.0",
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^3.0.1",


Thanks for the question, and I'm sorry for the late reply. We monitor questions using the safe-core tag, so as this question was not tagged, it slipped our attention.
However, your case seems obvious. Please make sure to use the checksummed address in the to field of your transaction data. Otherwise, the REST API will throw an error.
You are right, we will look internally at the error message. The ApiKit should throw a meaningful error message.
I hope this resolves your problem. If yes, please indicate this question as answered. And please don't hesitate to approach us again if you have encountered further issues with the Safe{Core} SDK.

To checksum an address you can use a web service like https://ethsum.netlify.app/; if you want to checksum it in your code, you can use Keccak256 and compare each character as explained here: https://cointelegraph.com/explained/ethereum-address-checksum-explained
Hope it helps; Best, Louis

The question isn’t how to checksum the address, it’s that the SDK doesn’t provide the right error, I had to dig into the API calls to figure out what the issue was. I’m using ethers.formatAddress to get the checksum but I’d like to be able to handle these errors meaningfully within my app
